# Backbone.sync - save and then fetch

Tags: javascript, node.js, backbone.js, express, mongoose

Is there a special type of `Backbone` request that you can create to do a "two-in-one" type operation like so:

normally, we would

- (step 1) save front-end collections to server
- (step 2) fetch new server collection objects to front-end

but is there a way to combine these two steps, so that when you do a save() of a certain collection, the server sends back the new objects that were not sent by save? or something? The semantics of `Backbone.sync` suggest the two steps above are what Backbone.sync would accomplish but I think sync just does a save, but not a fetch.

So, indeed, I am confused on how to keep the front-end collections synced with the backend with Backbone. A single save or a single fetch doesn't seem to be enough, you have to combine them to keep things synced. So, does Backbone.sync do that, or do I have write my own functionality for this?